# Accessing ArrayList of another class returning size 0

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been trying to access the arrayList from another file. However when i was running the size it was returning 0.

However running it on the class it is on would return a value. It seems that i can't access it from another class and that i am accessing it wrongly.

```
 public void test()
     {

    ArrayList<Events> eventArrayList = ( new ReadFile()).getList();



    System.out.println(eventArrayList.size());
     }



public class ReadFile
{


//Event arraylist
public ArrayList<Events> eventArrayList = new ArrayList<Events>();

    System.out.println(eventArrayList.get(0).events);

    public ArrayList<Events> getList()
{
    ArrayList<Events> eventArrayList = new ArrayList<Events>();

    return eventArrayList;


}

}
```

Comment: You return a new List without adding an element. So the Number of Elements in List is zero.

Comment: 1. Stop using more than one class. 2. Do whatever you're trying to do. 3. Go back and learn about classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are "resetting" the list every time you call `getList()`. Remove the first line of code.

```
public ArrayList<Events> getList() {
   return eventArrayList;   
}
```

Moreover, you should return `List<Events>` (you don't need to reveal the implementation used) and you shouldn't return the list but a copy of the list if you don't want other objects to change it (remember that it is passed by reference so if you change it, you will change it everywhere).